# blocksize error when mounting ufs drive in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mount, ufs

I have an external hard drive that I was using with a NAS4FREE computer. The computer died, and I would like to use the files on the external hard drive. NAS4FREE is based on freebsd, so the external hard drive is formatted as ufs.

I can almost get the external hard drive to mount on my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop. When I plug in the hard drive to my laptop, I am told that it didn't mount via a popup message. I check dmesg | tail and am informed that ufs filesystems can only be mounted in read-only mode. No problem, I input the mount command and give it the "-r" (that is, `sudo mount -r -t  ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /media/wshareTest`). It still doesn't mount, and dmesg | tail says "UFS: failed to set blocksize". The mountpoint exists, it's a mountpoint I'd created to test stuff with. Nothing is mounted there usually, only when I physically tell something to mount there is there anything there.

This is where I've been hitting a wall. As far as I can tell, the mount command doesn't have a blocksize setting for the ufs filetype.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

edit: I realize I should include the output of fdisk -l. Here it is:

```
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787025920 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60562 cylinders, total 976754645 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1   976754644  3907018576   ee  GPT
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind-of have a solution. -ish.

What I did was find an old netbook (an eeepc) and ran the nas4free livecd from it. This allowed me read/write access to the freebsd external hard drive, but nas4free has some issues with ntfs sometimes (so I didn't want to risk losing data by trying to connect it).

So, with a live version of nas4free running on my network, I connected my wife's ntfs external hard drive to my ubuntu laptop, connected to the nas4free box via the network and transferred files that way.

It's slow going, but it at least allows me to pull files off the ufs-formatted external hard drive.